# How to assign true or false value to column

Tags: c#, sql

How to assign a true or false value to a column. I am getting the count of values for an ID.  Then checking the count and assigning true or false boolean values to it. In the view side, I need to check if the value coming is true or false, and based on the true or false value I need to display different text in my view. But now my Item.Complete value is coming as false always. what I am doing wrong here?

```
var sqlst = @"select count(*) as columnCount, mem_name as Name, mem_add as address from my_table whereid = 1234"
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY_CONNECTION"].ConnectionString))
{
 connection.Open();
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlst, connection)

using (var sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sqlResult.Read())
{
    var checkcount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlResult["columnCount"].ToString());

    if (checkcount != 0)
    {
        Item.Complete = sqlResult["columnCount"].ToString() == "YES" ? true:false;
    }
    else
    {
        Item.Complete = sqlResult["columnCount"].ToString() == "NO" ? true: false;
    }

}
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a column named `ColumnCount` has a value called `YES`? Because that's not a word I'd associate with counting. (Also, it can't possibly be `YES` because then the `Convert.ToInt32` would not have worked. Either your column name is wrong, or your values are.)

Comment: My model is like this public bool columnCount { get; set; }.I can see getting integer values in checkcount .

Comment: You don't need a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to assign true false, as `==` returns a boolean.

Comment: If the column is a `BIT` and mapped to a boolean then the whole `.ToString()` dance is superfluous. `Item.Complete = (bool) sqlResult["columnCount"]` should do.

Comment: The query which you have provided, is wrong, it will error out as you are not using any `group by` clause with `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Passing `yes` and`No` Try using 1 and 0